# Binary XML file line: Duplicate id , tag null, or parent id with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working on an application in which I am having a drawerlayout and inside which I have a fragment.I am trying to use the jetpack navigation but the fragment gets the IllegalArgumentException issue.The code and the issue is as under

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.genie.vendor.ui.registration.RegistrationActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            style="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mainNavFragment"
            class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main_graph"
            tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_main_drawer"/>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.genie.vendorapplication/com.genie.vendor.ui.mainapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #36: Duplicate id 0x7f0900ec, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment

Comment: Delete  class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" from XML

Comment: @MMG - you need that (or `android:name`, they do the same thing) to inflate the fragment.

Comment: Can you include your Activity's code?

Comment: @ianhanniballake First it was android:name and i was facing the same issue

Comment: @Sam - they do the same thing, like I said, so that isn't your problem. Can you include your Activity's code?

Comment: did anyone everfind the solution?